# Implementing Gaussian mixture model for a HMM library

Tags: multivariate-analysis, hidden-markov-model, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I'm working on an alignment algorithm using [LAMP HMM library](http://www.cfar.umd.edu/~daniel/Site_2/Code.html).
This library supports Gaussian probability distribution but it does not seem to support Gaussian Mixture Model.

What I want is, to input continuous observations into multivariate Gaussians for training and alignment purposes.

It may be easy if I extend the current Gaussian model to support multiple Gaussians but I don't understand what codes to change and what codes to type as I'm a beginner to this topic.

Does anyone know of websites for learning such concepts?
Or can anyone show some pointers on how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to contact the developers of that library.

Comment: It would make more sense to use the latent variable representation of a mixture and to add those latent variables as a secondary HMM with an independence constraint...

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Multivariate Gaussian Mixture after I've read through this article here

[Gaussian Mixture Models and Expectation-Maximization](http://crsouza.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/gaussian-mixture-models-and-expectation.html)